# Wanting to check for a css class and if it's active change the image src value

Tags: jquery

Here is what I have so far, it isn't working right now and not sure why. Any thoughts?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  if ( $('#masthead').hasClass('is-fixed') ) {
    $('.site-logo-div').attr('src','second.jpg');
  }
})( jQuery );
```

*Edits:*
HTML

```
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header header-fixed" role="banner" style="top: 32px;">

<div class="site-logo-div"><a href="https://danzerpress.com/" class="custom-logo-link">
<imgsrc="https://example.com" class="custom-logo" alt="" itemprop="logo" "></a>
</div>
```

Wordpress themes js

```
 $( document ).scroll( function(){
        var header_parent = header_fixed.parent();
        var p_to_top = header_parent.offset().top;
        var st = $( document ).scrollTop();
        if( st > p_to_top && st > 0 ) {
            $wrap.addClass( 'is-fixed').removeClass( 'no-scroll' );
            header_fixed.addClass('header-fixed');
            header_fixed.css( 'top', topbar+'px' );
        } else {
            header_fixed.removeClass('header-fixed');
            header_fixed.css( 'top', 'auto' );
            $wrap.removeClass( 'is-fixed' ).addClass( 'no-scroll' );
        }
    });

}
```

});

Comment: There is any errors in console? Post the HTML structure please.

Comment: This code will be run for first time when loading the page, you need to add an event then check if the class exists. And where is the checking for `active`?

Comment: What you have will work fine, although as @sajib mentioned, it will only work on load. If you need this behaviour when the class is added you need to hook to the event that affects that class.

Comment: @sajibkhan yeah basically I am trying to find the active class is-fixed and if it is there to change the src to something new.

Comment: How is that class added? You either need to run this code when adding/removing the class, or use a `MutationObserver`. The latter is not supported in IE though.

Comment: the class is added when you scroll down. The class "is-fixed" is added to the nav.

Comment: Then that's where you need to add the `if` statement :)

Comment: Can you attach your sample HTML in the OP and JS for adding/removing `is-fixed` class?

Comment: ok just added the html

Comment: @sajibkhan as far as the js goes I am not sure where that is. I am using wordpress.

Comment: @sajibkhan actually jsut found it in the themes files and linked it

Comment: Where is adding 'is-fixed' class adding(maybe your are not linked correct js)?

Comment: @sajibkhan yeah sorry just added correct one

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  if ( $('#masthead').hasClass('is-fixed') ) {
    $('.site-logo-div a img').attr('src','second.jpg');
  }
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a custom event (`classChange` here) while adding or removing `is-fixed` class. Then inside the `classChange` event callback function change the image or else.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  var header_parent = header_fixed.parent();
    var p_to_top = header_parent.offset().top;
    var st = $( document ).scrollTop();
    if( st > p_to_top && st > 0 ) {
        $wrap.addClass( 'is-fixed').removeClass( 'no-scroll' );
        header_fixed.addClass('header-fixed');
        header_fixed.css( 'top', topbar+'px' );
        $('#masthead').trigger('classChanged');
    } else {
        header_fixed.removeClass('header-fixed');
        header_fixed.css( 'top', 'auto' );
        $wrap.removeClass( 'is-fixed' ).addClass( 'no-scroll' );
        $('#masthead').trigger('classChanged');    
    }
  });

  $('#masthead').on('classChange', function() {
     if ( $('#masthead').hasClass('is-fixed') ) {
       $('.site-logo-div').attr('src','second.jpg');
     } else {
       // do anything what you need when `is-fixed` class not exists
     }
  });
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try using the prop function !

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  if ( $('#masthead').prop('class')=="is-fixed" ) {
    $('.site-logo-div').attr('src','second.jpg');
  }
})( jQuery );
```